# how to bind regex d[1-13] pattern into devexpress ' TextEdit.Mask Property?

Tags: wpf, regex, devexpress, mask

my question is too short and simple. i have WPF devexpress text edit field. (i am new in devexp) Text edit field must be only digit character also max 13 character. For example; 123456789987 is correct. But 1234ght6789 is not correct 123445667777777744646 is not correct. How to give regex patterx in wpf devexpress mask structure?

Comment: I don't know about WPF but generally, the regex you are looking for is `/^\d{1,13}$/`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the range quantifier:

```
^\d{1,13}$
```

Comment: acheong87: i want to like that